# How can I hide menu tabs on a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My application email's a view.  However I would like to have this specific view ignore the menu tabs that are rendered by the _Layout.cshtml.   Is there a fairly easy way to make this happen?

Comment: How are you emailing this view? Could you provide a little more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by putting @Layout=null; at the top of the view.